# Is there any way you can mimic a localhost as domain name in node.js/express?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any way I can send response to an API asking for a domain name? I need it so I could test stuff locally without actually deploying it to the real website, which is failing and not loading the iFrame and displaying this error in the browser:
`Refused to display 'iFrameURL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`